# I suspect rtorrent is crashing my server. Which log should I check to find out?

Tags: server, log, rtorrent

I have a dedicated server, and it crashes every Sunday afternoon.

Which tools can help me to analyse the reason for these crashes?

In my `/var/log` directory I have these files:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root        root       0 janv.  1 06:25 alternatives.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root        root    1655 déc.  26 21:16 alternatives.log.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root        root     306 nov.  30 21:31 alternatives.log.2.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root        root    2387 oct.  26 17:55 alternatives.log.3.gz drwxr-x--- 2 root        adm     4096 janv. 12 06:25 apache2 drwxr-xr-x 2 root        root    4096 janv.  1 06:25 apt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root        root       0 janv.  1 06:25 aptitude
-rw-r--r-- 1 root        root     356 déc.   4 10:37 aptitude.1.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root        root     301 nov.  30 19:17 aptitude.2.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root        root    1653 oct.  26 17:44 aptitude.3.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root        adm  1095699 janv. 15 09:17 auth.log
-rw-r----- 1 root        adm  4765057 janv. 12 06:25 auth.log.1
-rw-r----- 1 root        adm   358694 janv.  5 06:25 auth.log.2.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root        adm  1031748 déc.  29 06:25 auth.log.3.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root        adm   334762 déc.  22 06:25 auth.log.4.gz
-rw-rw---- 1 root        utmp       0 janv.  1 06:25 btmp
-rw-rw---- 1 root        utmp       0 déc.   1 06:25 btmp.1
-rw-r----- 1 root        adm     5164 janv. 15 06:30 daemon.log
-rw-r----- 1 root        adm     6951 janv. 11 09:32 daemon.log.1
-rw-r----- 1 root        adm      710 janv.  5 02:45 daemon.log.2.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root        adm     5123 déc.  29 00:46 daemon.log.3.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root        adm     5231 déc.  21 16:16 daemon.log.4.gz drwxr-xr-x 2 root        root    4096 déc.   5 21:57 dbconfig-common
-rw-r----- 1 root        adm    18132 janv. 15 08:51 debug
-rw-r----- 1 root        adm    21490 janv. 10 11:09 debug.1
-rw-r----- 1 root        adm    21954 janv.  5 06:22 debug.2.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root        adm    15179 déc.  28 23:36 debug.3.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root        adm     4465 déc.  22 05:04 debug.4.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root        adm    46433 déc.  27 14:50 dmesg
-rw-r----- 1 root        adm    46433 déc.  27 14:36 dmesg.0
-rw-r----- 1 root        adm    12608 déc.  22 17:45 dmesg.1.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root        adm    12602 déc.  15 20:31 dmesg.2.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root        adm    12405 déc.  10 21:46 dmesg.3.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root        adm    12400 déc.   7 14:58 dmesg.4.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root        root    4559 janv. 15 09:14 dpkg.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root        root  135602 déc.  26 21:16 dpkg.log.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root        root    2768 nov.  30 21:31 dpkg.log.2.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root        root   27084 oct.  26 18:15 dpkg.log.3.gz drwxr-s--- 2 Debian-exim adm     4096 janv. 15 06:25 exim4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root        root   32160 déc.   5 21:50 faillog
-rw-r--r-- 1 root        root    1115 déc.  18 16:45 fontconfig.log drwxr-xr-x 2 root        root    4096 oct.  26 17:36 fsck drwxr-s--- 2 gitlog      adm     4096 déc.  22 17:45 git-daemon drwxr-xr-x 3 root   root    4096 oct.  26 17:39 installer
-rw-r----- 1 root        adm    18132 janv. 15 08:51 kern.log
-rw-r----- 1 root        adm    21490 janv. 10 11:09 kern.log.1
-rw-r----- 1 root        adm    21954 janv.  5 06:22 kern.log.2.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root        adm    45536 déc.  28 23:36 kern.log.3.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root        adm    14091 déc.  22 05:04 kern.log.4.gz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root        utmp  293460 janv. 15 09:13 lastlog
-rw-r----- 1 root        adm        0 oct.  26 17:42 lpr.log
-rw-r----- 1 root        adm        0 oct.  26 17:42 mail.err
-rw-r----- 1 root        adm        0 oct.  26 17:42 mail.info
-rw-r----- 1 root        adm        0 oct.  26 17:42 mail.log
-rw-r----- 1 root        adm        0 oct.  26 17:42 mail.warn
-rw-r----- 1 root        adm      588 janv. 15 06:25 messages
-rw-r----- 1 root        adm     1176 janv. 12 06:25 messages.1
-rw-r----- 1 root        adm      190 janv.  5 06:25 messages.2.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root        adm    29627 déc.  29 06:25 messages.3.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root        adm    10174 déc.  22 06:25 messages.4.gz drwxr-s--- 2 mysql       adm     4096 déc.   5 21:50 mysql
-rw-r----- 1 mysql       adm        0 déc.  18 16:47 mysql.err
-rw-r----- 1 mysql       adm        0 janv. 15 06:25 mysql.log
-rw-r----- 1 mysql       adm       20 janv. 14 06:25 mysql.log.1.gz
-rw-r----- 1 mysql       adm       20 janv. 13 06:25 mysql.log.2.gz
-rw-r----- 1 mysql       adm       20 janv. 12 06:25 mysql.log.3.gz
-rw-r----- 1 mysql       adm       20 janv. 11 06:25 mysql.log.4.gz
-rw-r----- 1 mysql       adm       20 janv. 10 06:25 mysql.log.5.gz
-rw-r----- 1 mysql       adm       20 janv.  9 06:25 mysql.log.6.gz
-rw-r----- 1 mysql       adm       20 janv.  8 06:25 mysql.log.7.gz drwxr-xr-x 2 root        root    4096 oct.  26 17:42 news drwxr-xr-x 2 ntp         ntp     4096 mai   12  2012 ntpstats drwxr-xr-x 2 root     root    4096 janv. 15 06:25 pgl
-rw------- 1 root        root      56 janv. 12 06:25 php5-fpm.log
-rw------- 1 root        root      56 janv.  5 06:25 php5-fpm.log.1
-rw------- 1 root        root      76 nov.   3 06:25 php5-fpm.log.10.gz
-rw------- 1 root        root     234 oct.  26 18:43 php5-fpm.log.11.gz
-rw------- 1 root        root      76 déc.  29 06:25 php5-fpm.log.2.gz
-rw------- 1 root        root     264 déc.  27 14:50 php5-fpm.log.3.gz
-rw------- 1 root        root     403 déc.  18 17:13 php5-fpm.log.4.gz
-rw------- 1 root        root     213 déc.  10 21:46 php5-fpm.log.5.gz
-rw------- 1 root        root     540 déc.   7 14:58 php5-fpm.log.6.gz
-rw------- 1 root        root     245 nov.  30 22:27 php5-fpm.log.7.gz
-rw------- 1 root        root      76 nov.  17 06:25 php5-fpm.log.8.gz
-rw------- 1 root        root     213 nov.  16 16:26 php5-fpm.log.9.gz drwxr-x--- 3 root        adm    20480 janv. 15 08:32 samba
-rw-r----- 1 root        adm     2898 janv. 15 09:17 syslog
-rw-r----- 1 root        adm    32172 janv. 15 06:25 syslog.1
-rw-r----- 1 root        adm     2134 janv. 14 06:25 syslog.2.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root        adm     1318 janv. 13 06:25 syslog.3.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root        adm     1163 janv. 12 06:25 syslog.4.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root        adm     1310 janv. 11 06:25 syslog.5.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root        adm     1341 janv. 10 06:25 syslog.6.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root        adm     3687 janv.  9 06:25 syslog.7.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root        adm        0 déc.  28 06:25 user.log
-rw-r----- 1 root        adm      147 déc.  27 14:47 user.log.1
-rw-r----- 1 root        adm       87 déc.  10 21:42 user.log.2.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root        adm      183 déc.   7 14:54 user.log.3.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root        adm      108 nov.  30 22:24 user.log.4.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root        adm        0 janv. 12 06:25 vsftpd.log
-rw-r----- 1 root        adm      429 janv. 10 20:54 vsftpd.log.1
-rw-r----- 1 root        adm     2929 janv.  4 17:12 vsftpd.log.2
-rw-r----- 1 root        adm   458314 déc.  28 13:01 vsftpd.log.3
-rw-r----- 1 root        adm     4986 déc.  21 14:33 vsftpd.log.4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root        utmp     384 janv. 15 09:13 wtmp
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root        utmp  216576 déc.  27 14:51 wtmp.1
```

I expect to see what happens on a Sunday afternoon in the apache2 log, but I don't have an rtorrent log. I suspect rtorrent is causing the crashes. What should I do to confirm this; which file will have the information I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view your logs from terminal like this:

```
cd /var/logs
less syslog
```

As mentioned in the [LinuxLogFiles](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxLogFiles) Wiki, you can browse them like this:

> "Press h for help, or q to quit. The cursor keys and page up/down keys will work as expected, and the slash key ("/") will do a case-sensitive search; the n key repeats the last search."

Error logs look like this: `/var/log/apport.log` and can be found by showing the contents of your logs directory:

```
ls /var/logs
```

You would view it the same way as `syslog` above.  Apache and Rtorrent are not for debugging or troubleshooting.  You can view your Apache error logs though:

```
less /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

Here are a couple resources for troubleshooting:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Troubleshooting
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting

Comment: Solved problem, it's due to number of torrents